# Is thre a better way to build it so it print all attributes from class/parent-class

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization

I have a `Student` class extending `Person` class, both class implemented `__str__` to list out all attributes in both `Person` and `Student` class.

However, I am having issues with trying to do a print of `__str__` in the `__init__` function as below.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
        print Person.__str__(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%15s%s\n" % ("Name: ", self.name)

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, n, sid, d):
        Person.__init__(self,n)
        self.sid = sid
        self.degree = d
        print Student.__str__(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return Person.__str__(self) + "%15s%s\n%15s%s\n"  % ("StudentID: ", self.sid, "Degree: ", self.degree)
```

When I execute the following

```
Jeff = Person("Jeff")
Cameron = Student('Cameron', 'U2314313', "Social Science")
```

it would produce something like:

```
Name: Jeff
Name: Cameron
Name: Cameron
StudentID:......
Degree:......
```

When initializing `Student`, it's calling `Student.__str__(self)`, and subsequently call `Person.__str__(self)` in order to bring back the name.

Just wondering if there's a better way to build the the structure so it's more usable and inline with the OO concept.

The result that I want is when I do the `__str__` for both `Student` or `Person`, it would list out all attributes, such as:

```
Name: Jeff
Name: Cameron
StudentID:......
Degree:......
```

and when I do something like `print Cameron`, it would still give me

```
Name: Cameron
StudentID:......
Degree:......
```

I know my code is duplicating it at the moment, but I can't figure out a way to make it work the way I intended... Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `getmembers` function of [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) module to get the all the members of the class dynamically.

Generic function to `return` attributes based on passed `class` or `class's object` can be define as:

```
import inspect

def get_attributes(class_object):
    attributes = inspect.getmembers(class_object, lambda a:not(inspect.isroutine(a)))
    return [a for a in attributes if not(a[0].startswith('__') and a[0].endswith('__'))]
```

Now the demonstration, on HOW this will work:

```
# Parent class
class MyClass(object):
    a = '12'
    b = '34'

# Child class
class MyChildClass(MyClass):
    c = '20'
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 20

get_attributes(MyClass)  <-- Parent Class
# returns: [('a', '12'), ('b', '34')]
# Return all the class attributes of "MyClass"

get_attributes(MyChildClass)  <-- Child Class
# returns: [('a', '12'), ('b', '34'), ('c', '20')]
# Returns all the class attributes of "MyChildClass"

get_attributes(MyChildClass())  <-- Object Of Child Class
# returns: [('a', '12'), ('b', '34'), ('c', '20'), ('x', 20)]
# Returns all the class + object attributes of "MyChildClass's object"
```

Comment: Didn't think of it this way THanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#super) which calls "parent's" function realization. I'm quoting parent because it is little different than in other programming languages. There is awesome presentation by Raymond Hettinger on Pycon 2015 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
        print self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%15s%s\n" % ("Name: ", self.name)

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, n, sid, d):
        Person.__init__(self,n)
        self.sid = sid
        self.degree = d
        print self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + "%15s%s\n%15s%s\n"  % ("StudentID: ", self.sid, "Degree: ", self.degree)
```

Here as you see when we need to call method of current class we just do `self.method()`, but if we need to call parent method we do `super().method()`

And i would suggest using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for string formating because it is more clear and readable.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
        print self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}\n".format(self.name)

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, n, sid, d):
        Person.__init__(self,n)
        self.sid = sid
        self.degree = d
        print self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + "StudentID: {}\nDegree: {}\n".format(self.sid, self.degree)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am already using `Person.__str__(self)` in Student's `__str__`, isn't it the same as using `super(Student,self).__str__(self)`?

Comment: Thanks re the suggestions on string format, but my goal is to have the column name (Student ID, Degree, Name, etc) to be right aligned (each take up 15 characters with spaces on the left) so it looks neater.

Comment: It is good practice, using super(), If you or someone else try to subclass this classes, they will stumble upon some unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Good pointer. I've changed them to use super(Student,self).__str__(self) now.